# How to combine contains with regular expression in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, data-science

Hello stackoverflow community,

I am doing a join in pyspark with two dataframes df1 and df2:

I want that the df2.col1 value has a space before and after and is a substring of df1.col1 When I try this, it doesnt work.

```
df1.join(df2, df1.col1.contains( " " + df2.col1 + " "), "leftsemi")
```

Could you help me?

Thank you

Comment: please add [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problems comes from the concatanation you're trying to perform. that's not how it should be done in spark :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1.join(
    df2,
    on=df1.col1.contains(F.contact(F.lit(" "), df2.col1, F.lit(" "))),
    how="leftsemi",
)
```

but without any reprex, that's just theory ...